# Open-source IDE's with Git support

Tags: git, open-source, ide

I'm having trouble finding an open-source IDE with support for Git. Are there any that you could point me to or recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an [Eclipse plugin in progress](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/).

Comment: The URL has now changed: http://www.eclipse.org/egit/

Answer (score 2):

There's [nbgit](http://code.google.com/p/nbgit/) for NetBeans in development, but it's not yet stable.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want a GUI for git, try [QGit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qgit).

Comment: I'm looking for something that I can integrate a little more than that, but thanks for the resource. I might end up using that if I can't find anything else, but I'll have to see if it actually saves me any more time over the command line.

Comment: It'll depend on your usage patterns - I've found it to be a real timesaver for searching the history, but it probably won't be of much use for write-only commands.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if such a thing exists in a stable form yet, but a good place to 
start your search is :

http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools

Answer (score 2):

I use Vim with [vcscommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90) plugin. Although the plugin supports a host of Version Control Systems, I use it specifically for Git.

Using VCSCommand, you can (almost) accomplish all the major features exposed by git right from within the vim.

VCSVimDiff command is one of the best features of VCSCommand plugin. You can view a colored diff right from inside Vim!

What more Vim and VCSCommand both are open source :)

**Side Note:**
*Vim along with NERD_Tree.vim, xml.vim, surround.vim and few other plugins, makes it a complete IDE that works pretty good (at least for me) with git. Search vim.org (or Google!!) for plugins that suits your requirement or taste.*

Answer (score 1):

The great [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/studio) has support (via plugins) for SVN, CVS, and Git (via [this plugin](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/EclipsePlugin)).  I'm still a noob with Aptana, and I haven't used Git yet, but it looks promising.