# What is the state of GIT IDE plugins in 2010?

Tags: eclipse, git, emacs, ide

My firm is switching to GIT and I'm curious as to the state of IDE plug ins for GIT. The [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353670/open-source-ides-with-git-support) was answered in 2008, and I'm hoping the answer no longer applies.

Answer (score 4):

[Magit](http://philjackson.github.com/magit/) for emacs is alive and well.

Alex Ott has a [nice overview](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsGit.html) of various git options for emacs.

Comment: Zip: As you tagged Emacs, I would start here. Magit is excellent.

Answer (score 2):

The [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) plugin for eclipse is in incubation phase.

I'm using Git in our production for last 6 months. Although we have installed the EGit plugin for eclipse I'm not much found of that. We are using the [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) project as the main git client along with [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) as the merge/diff tool. This combination works very well for us

Answer (score 2):

My experience with EGit is that its still not ready for any real use. My biggest gripe is that Egit tries to fit in the SVN usage model. So basically it is a crippled implementation, and therefore little incentive to switch from SVN. There are some pretty big gaps in features (no rebase) and the GUI is nowhere usable (that is also MHO of eclipse though). People complain about the git command-line, but somehow eGit managed to implement a GUI that was even less intuitive. Some other problems are:

1. git index is hidden, not sure if you can stage files in GUI
2. no rebase
3. no multi-branch history view
4. fetch/pull are buried in the menus
5. diffing between working copy and commits is not really implemented (except with quickdiff)
6. Egit and Eclipse synchronize feature do not play nice together
7. no way to do a git-status in the gui

Comment: I guess the EGit guys can't win: either the people used to the Eclipse SVN integration will complain that it's too different, or the advanced Git users will complain that it's too SVN-like... However, while I do agree it's less mature than e.g. Subversive, it's catching up quite quickly.